Could not load type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' from assembly 'System.Data
My Azure function is targeting .NET 4.8. When I deploy my function and try to run it, I get this error:

Exception while executing function: Notifier Could not load type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

After my investigation, I figured out that the runtime is trying to load System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection from System.Data not System.Data.SqlClient.
For your info I'm using v1 Azure function and when I check the artifact that I'm deploying the package is there. Could you help me with my query?
I tried to upgrade my Azure function code to v4 but got many other errors

Add this System.Data.SqlClient in csproj, so functions takes it from there and also use using System.Data.SqlClient; in files you are using it.

"After my investigation, I figured out that the runtime is trying to load System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection from System.Data not System.Data.SqlClient." - on .NET Framework, System.Data is the correct assembly location for SqlConnection, so: that's not necessarily the problem here; is any of your code targeting .NET Standard? I wonder whether that might add confusion

Hello @RithwikBojja thank you for your unswer . But i already have it in my csproj and i can see it in the dependencies dll . However the problem here is more related to the azure function that have a runtime that still pointing to the old version which have sqlconnection under system.data .

Please provide your function code and .csproj

@WalidOuhadda, Check if below suggestions help to fix the issue.

To resolve this, delete bin folder, Clean and Rebuild the project solution.
Install System.Data.SqlClient package version 4.*.* manually as @Rithwik mentioned in the comments.

NuGet\Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.8.6

I have created a Http triggered Azure Function v4 in .NET 4.8 and established SQL connection with below code.
Code Snippet:
 [Function("Function2")]
 public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

     var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

     try
     {
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
         {
             await conn.OpenAsync();
             string query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
             {
                 using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                 {
                     var results = new List<string>();

                     while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                     {
                         var data = reader[1].ToString(); 
                         results.Add(data);
                     }
                     await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(results);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
         _logger.LogError($"SQL Error: {ex.Message}");
         response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
         await response.WriteStringAsync("An error occurred while accessing the database.");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _logger.LogError($"Error: {ex.Message}");
         response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
         await response.WriteStringAsync("An unexpected error occurred.");
     }
     return response;
 }

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.18.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "sqlConnection": "<sql_connection_string>"
  }
}

Output:

Functions:
        Function2: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7273/api/Function2

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-11-04T13:54:08.045Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-11-04T13:55:03.191Z] Executing 'Functions.Function2' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=8623fa74-3XX8-8721-f25968fb7864)
[2024-11-04T13:55:03.401Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-11-04T13:55:07.874Z] Executed 'Functions.Function2' (Succeeded, Id=8623fa74-33f8-4608XX25968fb7864, Duration=4702ms)

